# how retrieve javascript function returned value in VB.net with webBrowser?

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I am using the WebBrowser control in my VB.NET application.

In webBrwoser i loaded html page that contains a javascript code like this:

```
function myfunction() {
  var x = 123
  alert(x)  
  return x
}
```

In vbnet code i write a code to invoke my function

```
WebBrowser.Document.Window.DomWindow.execscript("myFunction()","JavaScript")
```

this work fine, i see a alert in webBrowser, but in vbnet code, execscript return Nothing...
i need to read the result of javascript code invoked, like this

```
   dim s as String 
   s = WebBrowser.Document.Window.DomWindow.execscript("myFunction()","JavaScript")
   if s = "123" then
     msgbox("ok")
   end if
```

Comment: WebBrowser is no longer supported. You may consider using [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) instead. It uses MS Edge, so you'll need to ensure that it's installed. See the [WebView2 Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/release-notes) for version requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution: use InvokeScript!

```
dim s as String 
s = WebBrowser.Document.Window.InvokeScript("myFunction")
```

very important, with InvokeScript methid use only name of function, without ()